# Change of Basis for $2\times2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have the matrix basis $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\\end{bmatrix}$ , $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\\end{bmatrix}$ , $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\\\end{bmatrix}$, 
$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\\\end{bmatrix}$ ;

Then suppose I have the linear mapping $T:M \mapsto AM$ where $M$ and $A$ are 2x2 matrices, and $M$ is a member of the basis set; I want the basis $ _T[B]_T$ of this mapping.

Wikipedia says that I need to find $B^{-1}AB$ - where $A$ is the matrix of the mapping $T$ and $B$ is the basis matrix. What are $A$ and $B$ in matrix form? I do not understand this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{ij}$ be the entries of the matrix $A$.  Our basis is given by
$$
v_1 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad
v_2 = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \quad
v_3 = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}, \quad
v_4 = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$
We note that
$$
T(v_1) = a_{11}v_1 + a_{21} v_3\\
T(v_2) = a_{11}v_2 + a_{21} v_4\\
T(v_3) = a_{12}v_1 + a_{22} v_3\\
T(v_4) = a_{12} v_2 + a_{22} v_4
$$
Thus, the matrix $M$ with respect to this basis is
$$
M = 
\pmatrix{
a_{11} & 0 & a_{12} & 0\\
0 & a_{11} & 0 & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & 0 & a_{22} & 0\\
0& a_{21} & 0 & a_{22}
}
$$
Written in terms of the Kronecker product, we have $M = A \otimes I$.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at 
http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/m640_03c/hints/hint_hmk4_1.pdf

Khan academy also has a solution. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate_bases/change_of_basis/v/lin-alg-transformation-matrix-with-respect-to-a-basis